# How do I call a callable v2 Cloud Function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Flutter app that uses cloud functions. I upgraded one function to a v2 function and it no longer works. The function cannot be found. The function logs do not show that it is being called. It is in the `us-central1` region, as is the rest of the project.

`final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addMessage').call();`

Instead of `addMessage` I have tried the full function URL found in the firebase console, but that does not work either.

Function declaration:

```
exports.addMessage = onCall(async (request) => {
  //Run function
});
```

How do I call a v2 cloud function in flutter?

Comment: The V2 functions is just change in the functions API so the code in Flutter app should remain unchanged. What do you mean by "that does not work either"? Can you share any error that you get?

Comment: Error is `[firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object.` But function logs show the function does not even run.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/callable explains that v2 functions must be called with full URLs, and gives examples for the web SDK using `httpsCallableFromUrl`, but there appears to be no such option for the flutter SDK.

Comment: The v2 doc you refer to in your last comment indicates that "Rather than providing a function name, **provide a full URL to the client SDK**".  Have you tried `final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("https://--fullURL--").call();`?

Comment: Yes I have, I mention that in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conclusion: as of now you cannot call a v2 cloud function using the flutter `cloud_functions` package. You must use a regular http request to the full function URL (the `cloud_functions` package does not support using full URLs). You can use the dart `http` package to do this, handling the request and response manually.

Comment: did you ever get this to work? Side note, I don't think you can have a v2 function named "addMessage" has to be all lowercase.

Comment: It works with a regular http request. The cloud_functions package does not currently work with v2 functions. And yes, v2 functions must be lower case or they will not deploy.

Answer (score 3):

With `cloud_functions` version 4.1.0, it is now possible to call 2nd gen cloud functions:

```dart
FirebaseFunctions.instance
      .httpsCallableFromUrl("https://example.run.app/")
      .call({"paramter": "value"});
```

Note that you need to deploy the function before you can know what the URL will be. This will change in the future according to the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http#triggering_the_function

Answer (score 0):

For me the Reason I could not run the function was that I didn't authenticate the function for all (authenticated) users, as found here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating. The problem is that v2 function invocations are not allowed by default.

To do so follow these steps:

1. Go to the Google Cloud console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/?_ga=2.146762295.2040134096.1694704760-1196519054.1673428422&_gac=1.253897338.1694704907.CjwKCAjw3oqoBhAjEiwA_UaLtj6FwIgtn0m3gm-qTtruv9QegSx6EkctQWGsJlYrHXhTZwyWG7ns-xoCwDQQAvD_BwE

2. Click the **checkbox** next to the receiving function. (Don't click on the function itself.)
3. Click **Permissions** at the top of the screen. The Permissions panel opens.
4. Click **Add principal**.
5. In the New principals field, enter the identity of the calling function. This should be a service account email. (or all (Authenticated) Users depending on your case)
6. Select the role Cloud Functions > **Cloud Functions Invoker** from the Select a role drop-down menu.
7. Click Save.