# MissingPluginExecption when calling Cloud Function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a Firebase Cloud Function (written in Python) in my Flutter web app. When I run it locally it works fine, but when I have it hosted on Firebase (or in the Firebase emulator) I get this error:

> MissingPluginExecption(no implementation found for method FirebaseFunction#call on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_functions)`

The function is set up:

```
@https_fn.on_call()
def manualSignOut(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> Any:
    [code]
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('manualSignOut').call();
```

This appears to be what Firebase explains in [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#dart_2). I've also tried using the function URL as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76024597/6461854) and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by doing `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, and `flutter pub upgrade`. Not sure which of those three did it. Hope this helps anyone else with this issue.